# How to handle exception and send error to SSE client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, server-sent-events

I'm working with SSE using Spring's `SseEmitter` implementation.
In my case I want to handle error when project wasn't found on server side and send event with error message.

My first idea was to throw an exception from service's method and then handle it via `@ExceptionHandler` in class annotated with `@ControllerAdvice`. This didn't work, because `@ControllerAdvice` class knows nothing about SSE client.

After that I tried the following code:

```
private void sendError(String message, int status) {
    log.error("Processing report {} stopped with error '{}'", getContextLogMessage(), message);
    sseEmitter.completeWithError(new ApiError(message, HttpStatus.resolve(status)));
    sseEmitter.onCompletion(this::stopSelf); 
}
```

But by SSE client received the next message:

```
Received error
Event { type: 'error', status: 500, message: '' }
```

It looks like Spring's default error message was delivered to SSE client.

My SSE client's code:

```
const EventSource = require('eventsource')
const eventSource = new EventSource('http://localhost:8080/testing')

eventSource.onmessage = (e) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(e.data)
  if (data.status == null) {
    console.log(data)
  } else if (data.status === 'DONE') {
    console.log(data.status);
    eventSource.close()
  } else {
    console.log('status = ' + data.status)
  }
}

eventSource.onerror = (e) => {
  console.log('Received error')
  console.log(e)
  eventSource.close()
}
```

My questions is - does any possibility to handle it via `@ExceptionHandler` exist or no? Maybe I misunderstood something with Spring's SSE, I have used only `sseEmitter.send()` before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation, that is, I wanted to keep using the @ControllerAdvice and @ExceptionHandler I was already using.
Since my REST call returns a SseEmitter and produces text/event-stream, my existing ExceptionHandlers would not work as they return json.  So I just did the following.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class MyExceptionHandlerClass{

    @ExceptionHandler(MyException.class)
    public final ResponseEntity<Object> handleMyException(MyException ex){
        return ResponseEntity.status(ex.getStatus())
                   .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                   .body(ex.getMessage);
    }
}
```